# Coloring specific cells in a column without having to change the column ref in each range variable

Tags: vba

The code below works fine.  However, I feel there must be a better way of writing it to do the job easier and quicker. Each week i have to go into VB and change the column ref in the range, so the previous week is highlighted red.  Is there a way to enter the column ref once so all others are updated automatically or, even better, i can input the column ref in an input box?  week1 is i, week2 is j, week3 k and so on.  Thank you!

```
    Option Explicit

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim WSArray As Variant


Set WSArray = Sheets(Array("Baking HO", "Fresh Consol", "Moorebank", "Tamworth", "Canberra", "Fairbank", "Dandenong", "Carina", "Burleigh", "Townsville", _
           "Hobart", "Forestville", "Darwin", "Malaga", "Camellia", "EP-Total", "G144 Total", "G610 Total"))

For Each ws In WSArray
ws.Range("i6:i9,i17:i18,i22:i24,i28:i34,i39:i40,i46:i49,i51:i52,i55,i59:i62,i70:i74").Interior.Color = vbRed
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You can create a hidden worksheet with your values and populate your arrays from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass your sub a parameter to address the wanted week and use `Offset()` method of `Range` object, like follows

```
Option Explicit

Sub ColorPreviuosWeek(col As Long)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim WSArray As Variant

    Set WSArray = Sheets(Array("Baking HO", "Fresh Consol", "Moorebank", "Tamworth", "Canberra", "Fairbank", "Dandenong", "Carina", "Burleigh", "Townsville", _
               "Hobart", "Forestville", "Darwin", "Malaga", "Camellia", "EP-Total", "G144 Total", "G610 Total"))

    For Each ws In WSArray
        ws.Range("i6:i9,i17:i18,i22:i24,i28:i34,i39:i40,i46:i49,i51:i52,i55,i59:i62,i70:i74").Offset(, col - 1).Interior.Color = vbRed '<--| offset must be reduced by one so as to have offset 1 referencing column "i"
    Next
End Sub
```

so that

```
ColorPreviuosWeek 2 '<-- 2 stands for "week2"
```

will color column "J"

Comment: Fantastic! Does exactly what i want.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Are expecting something like this.

[Interactive UI for VBA-Excel](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/interactive-userform.html)